# libdbus-1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, filezilla, shared-libraries

```
[root@maomao bin]# find /usr/local/lib -name libdbus-1.so.3
/usr/local/lib/libdbus-1.so.3
[root@maomao bin]# cat /etc/ld.so.conf
include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/local/lib
[root@maomao bin]# ldconfig
[root@maomao bin]# filezilla
filezilla: error while loading shared libraries: libdbus-1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[root@maomao bin]# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
[root@maomao bin]# filezilla
filezilla: error while loading shared libraries: libdbus-1.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
[root@maomao bin]# cp /usr/local/lib/libdbus-1.so.3 ./
[root@maomao bin]# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./
[root@maomao bin]# filezilla
filezilla: error while loading shared libraries: libdbus-1.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
[root@maomao bin]# env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./
[root@maomao bin]# ls
filezilla  fzputtygen  fzsftp  libdbus-1.so.3
[root@maomao bin]#
```

I sure that I has "/usr/local/lib/libdbus-1.so.3". But I still can not run filezilla.

Comment: So it seems you have a 32 bit filezilla installed on a 64 bit centos (or I guess the wrong libdbus). That is where the problem is. So the next question was, how did you install filezilla? Did you build it from source, use yum (or a package manager) or did you download the binaries right from the internet?

Comment: can you put into a comment the output of this command `file filezilla` (this needs to be done in the directory where you have filezilla located)

Comment: "wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64". It's all you really need. Try searching the interwevbs for this.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI this question was asked almost 10 years ago, at that point I was 13, so please forgive my lack of skills back then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> libdbus-1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The runtime linker that tries to find needed libraries uses predefined search paths. These include paths like `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64` and a possibly a few other paths, as well as any paths given in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and some absolute or relative paths built in the binary that is run. (For details run `man ld.so` for the manual of the runtime linker.)

The path `/usr/local/lib` is probably not one of these default search paths.

> libdbus-1.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

You are mixing 32bit and 64bit binaries, which is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-3:i386
```

since you can have another arch. installed

Comment: what is the right library for say rhat or amazon ami for this?

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't tell you why libdbus-1.so.3 can't be found, but I would venture to guess that the `wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64` is because the filezilla you are using is 32bit and the libdbus in /usr/local/bin was compiled as 64bit shared objects. You need to make sure that programs and libraries are built with compatible architecture types

To tell if a program or shared object is built as 32 and 64 bit you can issue a command like this:

```
file /usr/local/lib/libdbus-1.so.3
file ./filezilla
```

What OS and version are you using?

Comment: centos 7. Thanks for telling. But I still want to know why lib not find.